# Pass Parameters in OData WebApi Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Using Web Api I have an OData EndPoint which can return Products from a database.

I have multiple databases with similar schemas, and want to pass a parameter in the URL to identify which database the Api should use.

**Current Odata Endpoint:**
http://localhost:62999/Products

**What I want:**
http://localhost:62999/**999**/Products

In the new Url, I pass in 999 (the database ID).

The database ID is intended to specify which database to load the product from.  For example `localhost:62999/999/Products('ABC123')` would load product 'ABC123' from database 999, but the next request, `localhost:62999/111/Products('XYZ789')` would load the product 'XYZ789' from database 111.

The Url below works, but I don't like it.
`localhost:62999/Products('XYZ789')?database=111`

Here is the code for the controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ErpApiController //extends ODataController, handles disposing of database resources
{
    public ProductsController(IErpService erpService) : base(erpService) { }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 50)]
    public IQueryable<ProductDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDto> queryOptions)
    {
        return ErpService.Products(queryOptions);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<ProductDto> Get([FromODataUri] string key, ODataQueryOptions<ProductDto> queryOptions)
    {
        var result = ErpService.Products(queryOptions).Where(p => p.StockCode == key);
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }               
}
```

I use Ninject to resolve which implementation of IErpService to inject into the controller by binding to a service provider:

`kernel.Bind<IErpService>().ToProvider(new ErpServiceProvider());`
 And the `ErpServiceProvider` inspects the url to identify the databaseId required by this request:

```
public class ErpServiceProvider : Provider<IErpService>
{
    protected override IErpService CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var databaseId = HttpContext.Current.Request["database"];

        return new SageErpService(new SageContext(GetDbConnection(databaseId)));
    }
}
```

The bit I am stuck on is how to define the Url parameter in the OData route config.

Normal WebApi routes can have parameters defined as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

But how do I define the parameters in the OData route config?

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<ProductDto>("Products");
        builder.EntitySet<WorkOrderDto>("WorkOrders");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Is this even where I should be defining the Url parameters?
I have also thought about using a Message Handler but I am not certain how this can be implemented either.

**UPDATE**
This question is trying to do the same thing as me: [How to declare a parameter as prefix on OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827188/how-to-decalre-a-parameter-as-prefix-on-odata)

But it is not clear how the parameter is to be read from the url. 
`var databaseId = HttpContext.Current.Request["database"];` returns null currently.
 Even after updating the route config to the following:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ErpApi",
        routeTemplate: "{database}/{controller}"                
    );

    // Web API configuration and services
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<ProductDto>("Products");
    builder.EntitySet<WorkOrderDto>("WorkOrders");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "{company}/",
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify... are you wanting to use the ID to specify which single Product to select from the database, or which database to select all of the Products from?

Comment: It is intended to specify which database to load the product from.  For example `localhost:62999/999/Products('ABC123')` would load product 'ABC123' from database 999, but the next request, `localhost:62999/111/Products('XYZ789')` would load the product 'XYZ789' from database 111.

Comment: hi philreed did you solved your problem? I've suggested a solution for your problem

Comment: Sorry no...Not yet. I tried your solution but the routing still does not work yet. I will be spending more time on the problem again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered a solution to pass dynamic parameter on OData, not sure if is the right one.

I've used this solution on a certain context, where the dynamic parameter was just to authenticate the client, but I think you can solve your problem in a similar way.

**Problem:** You wan't to pass a dynamic value at the URL request example: http://localhost:62999/{dynamicValue}/Products('ABC123'), but the ODataRouting will never route correctly, because of that extra /{dynamicValue} and the ODataControler "will not hit".
Using ApiController you could made a custom routing, but at OData you can't (at least I didn't found an easy way to do it, probably you had to made your own or extend the OData routing convention).

So as alternative **solution:**
If every request will have a dynamicValue for example: "http://localhost:62999/{dynamicValue}/Products" do the following steps:

1. Before routing the request Extract the dynamicValue (In my case, I've used an IAuthenticationFilter to intercept the message before it was routed, since  the parameter was related with authorization, but maybe for your case it makes more sense to use another thing)
2. Store the dynamicValue (somewhere on the request context)
3. Route the ODataController without the {dynamicValue}.
   /Products('ABC123') instead of /{dynamicValue}/Products('ABC123')

Here is the code:

```
// Register the ServiceRoute
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

  // Register the filter that will intercept the request before it is rooted to OData
  config.Filters.Add(CustomAuthenticationFilter>()); // If your dynamic parameter is related with Authentication use an IAuthenticationFilter otherwise you can register a MessageHandler for example.

  // Create the default collection of built-in conventions.
  var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();

  config.MapODataServiceRoute(
          routeName: "NameOfYourRoute",
          routePrefix: null, // Here you can define a prefix if you want
          model: GetEdmModel(), //Get the model
          pathHandler: new CustomPathHandler(), //Using CustomPath to handle dynamic parameter
          routingConventions: conventions); //Use the default routing conventions
}

// Just a filter to intercept the message before it hits the controller and to extract & store the DynamicValue
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter, IFilter
{
   // Extract the dynamic value
   var dynamicValueStr = ((string)context.ActionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["odatapath"])
        .Substring(0, ((string)context.ActionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["odatapath"])
        .IndexOf('/')); // You can use a more "safer" way to parse

   int dynamicValue;
   if (int.TryParse(dynamicValueStr, out dynamicValue))
   {
      // TODO (this I leave it to you :))
      // Store it somewhere, probably at the request "context"
      // For example as claim
   } 
}

// Define your custom path handler
public class CustomPathHandler : DefaultODataPathHandler
{
    public override ODataPath Parse(IEdmModel model, string serviceRoot, string odataPath)
    {
        // Code made to remove the "dynamicValue"
        // This is assuming the dynamicValue is on the first "/"
        int dynamicValueIndex= odataPath.IndexOf('/');
        odataPath = odataPath.Substring(dynamicValueIndex + 1);

        // Now OData will route the request normaly since the route will only have "/Products('ABC123')"
        return base.Parse(model, serviceRoot, odataPath);
    }
}
```

Now you should have the information of the dynamic value stored at the context of the request and OData should route correctly to the ODataController. Once your there at your method, you can access the request context to get information about the "dynamic value" and use it to choose the correct database

Comment: I have this working now but I had to make some changes to your answer.  I would still like to give you credit as you set me on the correct path to the solution, but the answer you have posted isn't what I have used exactly.

Comment: The main change was to define a route template when configuring the OData route: `routePrefix: "erp/{company}"`. This allowed me to call `var company = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["company"];` (with the required null checks), this mean't that I didnt not have to parse the string looking for indexes of '/' as you have in your filter.

Answer (score 3):

These APIs have likely changed quite a bit since this original post. But I was able to accomplish this by making the default data route prefix contain the parameter:

`b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/{customerName}", GetEdmModel());`

In my scenario, I have a database per customer, so I want the route prefix to accept the name of the customer (database):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseMvc(b =>
    {
        b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/{customerName}", GetEdmModel());
    });
}
```

Example controller (*note `customerName` parameter on the action*):

```
public class BooksController : ODataController
{
    private IContextResolver _contextResolver;

    public BooksController(IContextResolver contextResolver)
    {
        _contextResolver = contextResolver;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get(string customerName)
    {
        var context = _contextResolver.Resolve(customerName);
        return Ok(context.Books);
    }
}
```

Then you can hit the URL like: `https://localhost/odata/acmecorp/Books`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this solution. Works so far with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData@7.2.2.

Comment: Thanks for that! I would buy you a beer if I could :D So simple and elegant. And works with 8.0.11 as well.